# POI: setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) fails because of Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My Java application reads an xls file and presents it on a JTable. So far so good.

When I try to save my worksheet, I iterate over row,col in my JTable and:

```
String str = (String) Table.getValueAt(row, col);

HSSFRow thisrow = sheet.getRow(row);
HSSFCell thiscell = thisrow.getCell(col);
if(thiscell==null) thiscell = thisrow.createCell(col);

switch(inferType(str)) {
    case "formula":
        thiscell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
        thiscell.setCellFormula(str.substring(1));
        break;
    case "numeric":
        thiscell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        thiscell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(str));
        break;
    case "text":
        thiscell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        thiscell.setCellValue(str);
        break;
    }
```

But when I run over a cell which was originally a formula, say `A1/B1`, that is `#DIV/0!` at the moment, `setCellType` fails.

With much investigation I found out that when `setCellType` is called, it tries to convert the old content to the new type. BUT, this didn't seem a problem to me, since every table formula cell was already a formula in the xls. **Hence, I am never actually changing types.**

Even so, when I call `setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)` on a cell that is already a formula, but it is evaluated to `#DIV/0!`, I get an conversion exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a error formula cell
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:648)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.checkFormulaCachedValueType(HSSFCell.java:653)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(HSSFCell.java:678)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.java:317)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.java:283)
```

Actually my only workaround is, before `setCellType`:

```
if(thiscell.getCachedFormulaResultType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR)
    thiscell = thisrow.createCell(col);
```

This IS working, but I lose the original layout of the cell, e.g. its colors.

How can I properly `setCellType` if the Cell is a formula with evaluation error?

Comment: What happens if you skip `thiscell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);` and just go with only `thiscell.setCellFormula(str.substring(1));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the mailing list of poi-apache:

> There are two possible scenarios when setting value for a formula
>   cell;
>
> 1. Update the pre-calculated value of the formula. If a cell contains formula then cell.setCellValue just updates the pre-calculated
>      (cached) formula value, the formula itself remains and the cell type
>      is not changed
> 2. Remove the formula and change the cell type to String or Number:
>
> cell.setCellFormula(null); //Remove the formula
>
> then cell.setCellValue("I changed! My type is CELL_TYPE_STRING now"");
>   or cell.setCellValue(200); //NA() is gone, the real value is 200
>
> I think we can improve cell.setCellValue for the case (1). If the new
>   value conflicts with formula type then IllegalArgumentException should
>   be thrown.
>
> Regards, Yegor

Still, it *does* feel like a workaround to me. But everything is now working.

`cell.setCellFormula(null)` before **any** `setCellType` should prevent conversion failure, because the first will discard the cached content.